# How to Put Duplicate Records a Display Error?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys please help me =(
This is the code but it's not working.
[image: This is the code but it's not working.]
this is the example record data
[image: this is the example record data]
thank you guys =))

display an error message if the record already exists.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: [What do you mean "It doesn't work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work)